# add dynamic order to add remove html input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have this code for add/remove dynamic input:

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<tr />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
  var number = Math.random();
    return '<td id="' + number + '"><input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" class="form-control" /></td>' + '<td><select name="" class="form-control"><option> Select</option><option> Male</option><option> Female</option></select></td>' + '<td><input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="radio" value = "' + value + '" /></td>' + '<td><input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="checkbox" value = "' + value + '" /></td>'+'<td><input name = "order" type="number" value = "" /></td>' + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></td>'
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h5 class="text-center">Dynamic Control : Text Box, Dropdown List, Radiobox and Checkbox</h5>
<section class="container">
<div class="table table-responsive">
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>TextBox</td>
        <td>Dropdown List</td>
        <td>Radio</td>
        <td>CheckBox</td>
        <td>Order</td>
        <td>BTN</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="TextBoxContainer">
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">
    <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Add more controls"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp; Add&nbsp;</button></th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
</section>
```

this code work true for me but how do can i add dynamic order(`from 1 to ...`) for each row(`td`). my mean add order input from number 1 and add +1 number from last order number.

[demo is here](https://jsfiddle.net/pwe1uyhc/)

update: (my need)

[image]

Comment: Please update your code and show us your best attempt at resolving this issue yourself.

Comment: @devlincarnate: see my update

Answer (score 0):

You need to just modify the JS code logic. The below example shows the use of variable count and its usage.
Here, the variable count is declared as 1 initially and as per the "Add" click the count value has been incremented by 1. Same way the count is been decremented by 1 when we are deleting/removing the the "tr" column.

```
$(function () {
  var count = 1;
  $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
    var div = $("<tr />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox("", count));
    $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    count++;
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    count--;
  });
});
```

The click function will have one more argument count which is used for the rendering/displaying of the count value in the order field.

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value, count) {
  var number = Math.random();
  return '<td id="' + number + '">
            <input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" class="form-control" />
          </td>' + '
          <td>
            <select name="" class="form-control">
              <option> Select</option>
              <option> Male</option>
              <option> Female</option>
            </select>
          </td>' + '
          <td>
            <input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="radio" value = "' + value + '" />
          </td>' + '
          <td>
            <input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="checkbox" value = "' + value + '" />
          </td>'+'
          <td>
            <input name = "order" type="number" value = "' + count + '" /></td>' + '
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button>
          </td>'
}
```

The above code works when we are removing the row from the last column.
If you are removing in-between the row from the list of **tr** tags you will find the order columns values are not arranged properly.

The below code is used for the removing the **tr** tag in-between the row and as well as the from the last **tr** tag. This code will be flexible for removing the **tr** row from anywhere in the list as well as updating the order row in the incremental way.

```
 $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    var deleteElement = $(this).closest("tr");
    var countOfDeleteElement = $(deleteElement).find("#order").val();
    var lastElementCount = count - 1;
    if (countOfDeleteElement !== lastElementCount) {
      // It will come inside this if block when we are removing inbetween element.
      var remainingElements = deleteElement.nextAll('tr');  // get all the below elemnts from the removing element.
      // updating all remainingElements value of the order column
      remainingElements.each((i, ele) => {
        $(ele).find("#order").val(countOfDeleteElement);
        countOfDeleteElement++;
      })
    }
    deleteElement.remove();
    count--;
});
```